# Bitstring Physics

Tags: code-golf, array, random

## Background

Yes, bitstring physics is [a real thing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=363694&punumber%3D2948%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A8339%29%26pageNumber%3D2).
The idea is to construct a new theory of physics using only strings of bits that evolve under a probabilistic rule... or something.
Despite reading a couple of papers about it, I'm still pretty confused.
However, the bitstring universe makes for a nice little code golf.

## Program Universe

Bitstring physics takes place in a so-called *program universe*.
At each step of the evolution of the universe, there is a finite list `L` of bitstrings of some length `k`, starting with the two-element list `[10,11]` where `k = 2`.
One timestep is processed as follows (in Python-like pseudocode).

```
A := random element of L
B := random element of L
if A == B:
    for each C in L:
        append a random bit to C
else:
    append the bitwise XOR of A and B to L
```

All random choices are uniformly random and independent of each other.

## Example

An example evolution of 4 steps might look like the following.
Start with the initial list `L`:

```
10
11
```

We randomly choose `A := 10` and `B := 10`, which are the same row, which means we need to extend each string in `L` with a random bit:

```
101
110
```

Next, we choose `A := 101` and `B := 110`, and since they are not equal, we add their XOR to `L`:

```
101
110
011
```

Then, we choose `A := 011` and `B := 110`, and again append their XOR:

```
101
110
011
101
```

Finally, we choose `A := 101` (last row) and `B := 101` (first row), which are equal, so we extend with random bits:

```
1010
1100
0111
1010
```

## The Task

Your task is to take a nonnegative integer `t` as input, simulate the program universe for `t` timesteps, and return or print the resulting list `L`.
Note that `t = 0` results in the initial list `[10,11]`.
You can output `L` as a list of lists of integers, list of lists of boolean values or a list of strings; if output goes to STDOUT, you may also print the bitstrings one per line in some reasonable format.
The order of the bitstrings is significant; in particular, the initial list cannot be `[11,10]`, `[01,11]` or anything like that.
Both functions and full programs are acceptable, standard loopholes are disallowed, and the lowest byte count wins.

Comment: Can we limit the bit string length (that is: may I use 32 bit numbers and bit operations)?

Comment: @edc65 No, the length of the strings can get arbitrarily high.

Comment: @Zgarb well, your challenge your rules, but the length grows approximately  with `log2(#strings)`, so by the time you hit 32 you will be using 128 GB RAM

Comment: @edc65 The expected time and memory requirements for getting over 32 bits are astronomical, but that's just fitting since we're simulating a universe. ;)

Comment: Do we have to preserve leading zeroes? (Since the universe starts with leading 1s, and bits are never prepended or elements removed, the length of any element could always be inferred.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Leading zeroes should be preserved.

Comment: Is this _Bit-string Physics_ a crackpot idea?  I haven't read the whole paper, but the phrase 
*We have used bit-string physics to provide a theory in which the approximation hbar c/e2 = 22 - 1 + 23 - 1 + 27 - 1 = 137 makes sense in terms of a computer algorithm and information theory* strikes me as a bit ... numerological.

Comment: Also, your "equation of motion" seems different from the one  in the paper, _We start from a universe of bit-strings of the same length which grow in length by a random bit, randomly chosen for each string whenever XOR between  two strings gives the null string; else the resulting non-null string is adjoined to the universe._ Is that intentional?

Comment: @xebtl It does seem crazy to me too. I remember reading a justification for the algorithm somewhere, and it sounded more like bad pseudo-philosophy than physics. Also, your description of the algorithm seems to match my version, maybe I'm misunderstanding you in some way.

Comment: @Zgarb I read *whenever XOR between two strings gives the null string* as "there is a pair of strings that are equal" rather than "two randomly chosen strings are equal".  Of course, it does not matter much for the challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
u?+RO2GqFKmOG2aGxVFKQ*]1U2
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3F%2BRO2GqFKmOG2aGxVFKQ*%5D1U2&input=0&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
                              implicit: Q = input number
                     *]1U2    the initial list [[1,0], [1,1]]
u                   Q         reduce, apply the following expression Q times to G = ^
          mOG2                  take two random elements of G
         K                      store in K
       qF                       check if they are equal
 ?                              if they are equal:
  +RO2G                           append randomly a 0 or 1 to each element of G
                                else:
              aG                  append to G
                xVFK              the xor of the elements in K
```

Comment: `xVFK` is equivalent to `xMK`.

Comment: @isaacg No, `xVFK` is equivalent to `xMCK`, same byte count.

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, <s>42</s> <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

*1 byte saved by Sp3000.*

```
B2b2/q~{:L_]:mR_~#L@~.^a+L{2mr+}%?}*p
```

### Explanation

Create the initial state as a base-2 number:

```
B2b e# Push the the binary representation of 11: [1 0 1 1]
2/  e# Split into chunks of 2 to get [[1 0] [1 1]]
```

And then perform the main loop and pretty-print the result at the end:

```
q~       e# Read and eval input t.
{        e# Run this block t times.
  :L     e#   Store the current universe in L.
  _]     e#   Copy it and wrap both copies in an array.
  :mR    e#   Pick a random element from each copy.
  _~     e#   Duplicate those two elements, and unwrap them.
  #      e#   Find the second element in the first. If they are equal, it will be found at
         e#   index 0, being falsy. If they are unequal, it will not be found, giving
         e#   -1, which is truthy.

         e#   We'll now compute both possible universes for the next step and then select
         e#   the right one based on this index. First, we'll build the one where they were
         e#   not equal.

  L@~    e#   Push L, pull up the other copy of the selected elements and unwrap it.
  .^     e#   Take the bitwise XOR.
  a+     e#   Append this element to L.

  L      e#   Push L again.
  {      e#   Map this block onto the elements in L.
    2mr+ e#     Append 0 or 1 at random. 
  }%     
  ?      e#   Select the correct follow-up universe.
}*
p        e# Pretty-print the final universe.
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=YZ%5DYfbq~%7B%3AL_%5D%3AmR_~%23L%40~.%5Ea%2BL%7B2mr%2B%7D%25%3F%7D*p&input=4)

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, <s>141</s> 129 bytes

```matlab
t->(L=Any[[1,0],[1,1]];for i=1:t r=1:length(L);A=L[rand(r)];B=L[rand(r)];A==B?for j=r L[j]=[L[j],rand(0:1)]end:push!(L,A$B)end;L)
```

Nothing clever. Creates an unnamed function that accepts an integer as input and returns an array of arrays. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=t->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
function f(t)
    # Start with L0
    L = Any[[1,0], [1,1]]

    # Repeat for t steps
    for i = 1:t
        # Store the range of the indices of L
        r = 1:length(L)

        # Select 2 random elements
        A = L[rand(r)]
        B = L[rand(r)]

        if A == B
            # Append a random bit to each element of L
            for j = r
                L[j] = [L[j], rand(0:1)]
            end
        else
            # Append the XOR of A and B to L
            push!(L, A $ B)
        end
    end

    # Return the updated list
    L
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f(4)
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1,0,1,0]
 [1,1,1,1]
 [0,1,1,0]
 [0,1,0,0]

julia> f(3)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1,0,1,1]
 [1,1,1,0]
 [0,1,0,1]
```

Saved 12 bytes thanks to M L!

Comment: You can shave it down to **133 characters** if you use the ternay operator instead of if/else and if you change `A=something;B=something else to A,B=something,something else`: `t->(L=Any[[1,0],[1,1]];for i=1:t r=1:length(L);A,B=L[rand(r)],L[rand(r)];A==B?(for j=r L[j]=[L[j],rand(0:1)]end):(push!(L,A$B))end;L)`

Comment: @ML: Nice, thanks. I hadn't thought to use the ternary operator. But you don't actually need the parentheses in the ternary, which saves another 4 over your suggestion. Assigning `A` and `B` separately is actually the same length as assigning them together, so I left that part as is. Thanks again for your suggestion!

Comment: You’re welcome. Ah, I see. Yes, the parentheses aren’t necessary.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 141

I tried a few different methods, but the best I could get was relatively straightforward. Thanks to @Sp3000 for 15 chars or so (and for teaching me about the existence of `int.__xor__`).

```py
from random import*
L=[[1,0],[1,1]];C=choice
exec"A=C(L);B=C(L);L=[L+[map(int.__xor__,A,B)],[x+[C([1,0])]for x in L]][A==B];"*input()
print L
```

Comment: Here's 141: [link](http://ideone.com/P6QgXm)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 34

```
u?+RO`TGqJOGKOG+Gsm`s!dqVJKQ[`T`11
```

Uses reduce to apply each iteration. I'll explain when I'm done golfing.

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3F%2BRO%60TGqJOGKOG%2BGsm%60s!dqVJKQ%5B%60T%6011&input=4&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## K, <strike>46</strike> <strike>53</strike> 46 bytes

```
{x{:[~/t:2?x;{x,*1?2}'x;x,,,/~=/t]}/(1 0;1 1)}
```

A good chunk of the size (about 7 bytes) of this is do to the fact that K has no `xor` operator, so I had to implement one myself. Originally, I used a list of strings, followed by realizing that was insanely stupid. So now I cut off the 7 bytes again!

Before:

```
{x{:[~/t:2?x;{x,*$1?2}'x;x,,,/$~=/(0$')'t]}/$:'10 11}
```

@JohnE pointed out in the comments that the initial state was supposed to be hardcoded, which cost 7 extra bytes. :/

Comment: My reading of the problem spec is that you must always begin with the hardcoded "universe" `(1 0;1 1)`- your program accepts this as input.

Comment: @JohnE Fixed. However, there's no guarantee this will work because I didn't test the changes; I just tried the ending part in your oK repl...

Comment: Seems to work fine in Kona as well.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 152

A function, using strings (with numbers it should be shorter, but in javascript bit operations are limited to 32 bit integers).

Test in Firefox using the snippet below.

```js
F=(t,L=['10','11'],l=2,R=n=>Math.random()*n|0,a=L[R(l)],b=L[R(l)])=>
   t--?a==b
     ?F(t,L.map(x=>x+R(2)),l)
     :F(t,L,L.push([...a].map((x,p)=>x^b[p]).join('')))
  :L
  
test=_=>O.innerHTML=F(+I.value).join('\n')
```

```css
#I{width:3em}
```

```html
<input id=I value=10><button onclick=test()>-></button><pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>241</s> 233 bytes

That's kind of long.

```
a=[[1,0],[1,1]];for(b=prompt();b--;)if(c=a.length,d=a[c*Math.random()|0],e=a[c*Math.random()|0],d+""==e+"")for(f=0;f<c;f++)a[f].push(2*Math.random()|0);else{g=[];for(h=0;h<d.length;h++)g.push(d[h]^e[h]);a.push(g)}alert(a.join("\n"));
```

Comment: [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) compressed it saving 8 bytes.

Comment: 216 bytes: `for(b=prompt(a=[[1,0],[1,1]]),R=Math.random;b--;){c=a.length;d=a[c*R()|0];e=a[c*R()|0];if(d+""==e+"")for(f=0;f<c;f++)a[f].push(2*R()|0);else{for(h=0,g=[];h<d.length;)g.push(d[h]^e[h++]);a.push(g)}}alert(a.join("\n"))`, produces the desired output 3/5 of the time.

Comment: 217 bytes: `for(b=prompt(a=[[1,0],[1,1]]),R=Math.random;b--;){c=a.length;d=a[c*R()|0];e=a[c*R()|0];if(d+""==e+"")for(f=0;f<c;f++)a[f].push(2*R()|0);else{g=[];for(h=0;h<d.length;h++)g.push(d[h]^e[h]);a.push(g)}}alert(a.join("\n"))`, works 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

## K, <s>45</s> <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
{x{(x,,~=/t;{x,1?2}'x)@~/t:2?x}/1,'!2}
```

The structure of my answer is quite similar to that of @kirbyfan64sos, but instead of strings I used 1/0 vectors and I avoid the need for a conditional (`:[ ; ; ]`) by instead indexing into a list.

A few runs:

```
  {x{(x,,~=/t;{x,1?2}'x)@~/t:2?x}/1,'!2}3
(1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1
 0 1 1 1)

  {x{(x,,~=/t;{x,1?2}'x)@~/t:2?x}/1,'!2}3
(1 0 0
 1 1 0
 0 1 0
 1 0 0)

  {x{(x,,~=/t;{x,1?2}'x)@~/t:2?x}/1,'!2}3
(1 0 0
 1 1 0
 0 1 0
 1 1 0)
```

### Edit:

Saved four bytes with a more compact way to build the initial universe:

```
1,'!2     / new
(1 0;1 1) / old
```

### Edit2:

I forgot that "choose" can take a list as its right argument:

```
  2?"abcd"
"dc"
  2?"abcd"
"cc"
  2?"abcd"
"ca"
```

So I can simplify part of this. Credit where it's due, Kirby got this trick before I did.

```
2?x    / new
x@2?#x / old
```

Comment: Dang, sometimes I think I know K, then I see your answers... :O

Comment: I think this solution definitely counts as a team effort!

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL (2012+), 1019

I'm really sorry this is nowhere near competitive, but to be honest I didn't think I could get this to work and had to post it once I did.  I did try to golf it a bit :)

To handle the binary/integer conversions I had to create a couple of scalar functions (513 of the bytes). `A` goes from integer to a bit string. `B` does the reverse.

```
CREATE FUNCTION A(@ BIGINT)RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX);
WITH R AS(SELECT @/2D,CAST(@%2 AS VARCHAR(MAX))M
UNION ALL
SELECT D/2,CAST(D%2 AS VARCHAR(MAX))+M
FROM R
WHERE D>0)SELECT @S=M FROM R WHERE D=0
RETURN @S
END
CREATE FUNCTION B(@ VARCHAR(MAX))RETURNS BIGINT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @I BIGINT;
WITH R AS(SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@,1)AS BIGINT)I,1N,LEFT(@,LEN(@)-1)S
UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(S,1)AS BIGINT)*POWER(2,N),N+1,LEFT(S,LEN(S)-1)
FROM R
WHERE S<>''
)SELECT @I=SUM(I)FROM R
RETURN @I
END
```

Then there is the procedure.  `@C` is the number of steps

```
DECLARE @C INT=9
DECLARE @ TABLE(S VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @R VARCHAR(MAX)
INSERT @ VALUES('10'),('11')
WHILE(@C>=0)
BEGIN
SET @C-=1
SELECT @R=CASE WHEN MAX(S)=MIN(S)THEN''ELSE RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',99)+dbo.A(dbo.B(MAX(S))^dbo.B(MIN(S))),LEN(MAX(S)))END
FROM(SELECT TOP 2S,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT\))N FROM @,(VALUES(1),(1),(1))D(D)ORDER BY RAND(CAST(NEWID()AS VARBINARY(50))))A
IF @R=''UPDATE @ SET S=CONCAT(S,ROUND(RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(50))),0))
ELSE INSERT @ VALUES(@R)
END
SELECT * FROM @
```

Ten thousand iterations took around 2 minutes and returned 9991 rows

```
1001001100110
1101001001110
0111100100101
1111100001011
1111001010011
0110101001101
...
1110101000100
1111011101100
1100001100010
0110010001001
1110100010100
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 37 bytes

Obvious, just follows psuedocode. Probably can golf a lot.

```
KPP^,1Z2VQ=K?m+dO1KqFJ,OKOKaKxVhJeJ;K
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KPP%5E%2C1Z2VQ%3DK%3Fm%2BdO1KqFJ%2COKOKaKxVhJeJ%3BK&input=4&debug=1).

Comment: You need `O2` instead of `O1`. `O1` gives you a random number from the range `U1 = [0]`.

Comment: So you're always appending a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 106 bytes

```
Nest[If[Equal@@#,Map[#~Append~RandomInteger[]&],Append[BitXor@@#]]&[#~RandomChoice~2]@#&,{{1,0},{1,1}},#]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 102

```
#!perl -p
@l=qw(10 11);$_=$l[rand@l]^$l[rand@l],$_|=y//0/cr,@l=/1/?(@l,$_):map{$_.~~rand 2}@l for 1..$_;$_="@l"
```

Try [me](http://ideone.com/KAQAyx).

Answer (score 0):

### R, 186

```
L=list(0:1,c(1,1))
if(t>0)for(t in 1:t){A=sample(L,1)[[1]]
B=sample(L,1)[[1]]
if(all(A==B)){L=lapply(L,append,sample(0:1, 1))}else{L=c(L,list(as.numeric(xor(A,B))))}}
L
```

Nothing magical here. Enter the value for `t` in the R console and run the script. It's hard to "golf" R code but here's a more readable version:

```
L <- list(0:1, c(1, 1))
if(t > 0) {
  for(t in 1:t) {
    A <- sample(L, 1)[[1]]
    B <- sample(L, 1)[[1]]
    if (all(A == B)) {
      L <- lapply(L, append, sample(0:1, 1))
    } else {
      L <- c(L,list(as.numeric(xor(A, B))))
    }
  }
}
L
```

Comment: You can save a number of characters by assigning `sample` to a variable. eg `s=sample`, then use s rather than sample.  Unfortunately I think your method of appending a random bit in the `lapply` will end up with one random sample being added to all items in the list. `lapply(L,function(x)append(x,sample(0:1,1)))` appears to work, but at a cost. You can replace you `as.numeric` with `1*` which should get some back.

Comment: Good catch on both points, and a nice coercion trick too

Comment: Also just noticed your count is out.  I make it 168 using [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 82

Pretty much straight-forward. Compared with other non-golfing languages, ruby seems to do well with its large standard library.

```
->t{l=[2,3]
t.times{a,b=l.sample 2
a.equal?(b)?l.map!{|x|x*2+rand(2)}:l<<(a^b)}
l}
```

Sample output for t=101010 :

```
[9, 15, 6, 13, 5, 12, 10, 11, 5, 4, 15, 13, 2, 7, 11, 9, 3, 3, 8, 6, 3, 13, 13, 12, 10, 9, 2, 4, 14, 9, 9, 14, 15, 7, 10, 4, 10, 14, 13, 7, 15, 7]
```